# How to apply scroll bar for multiple divs in main div

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I want to apply the scroll bar for child divs without scrolling the header

I had tried

```
overflow-y:auto and overflow-y:scroll
```

but none of them are working

My main div height is 500px and i am giving height as 200px for my child divs i need to apply scroll if my child child div height exceeds 200px with fixing the headers which is not getting applied with my below css

```
<div style="padding:20px; max-height:500px;overflow-y:auto" id="divMain">
<div style="padding:20px; max-height:200px;overflow-y:auto" id="childdiv1">
</div>
<div style="padding:20px; max-height:200px;overflow-y:auto" id="childdiv2">
</div>
<div style="padding:20px; max-height:200px;overflow-y:auto" id="childdiv3">
</div>
<div style="padding:20px; max-height:200px;overflow-y:auto" id="childdiv4">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: take a look at this : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow

Comment: i had already tried but my max height for main div is 500 px so even when i use max height for divs as 300 or 200 px also its not working

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do ? could you explain more what you want to achieve ? (Edit your question)

Comment: Overflow only comes into play if there is enough content in an element to overflow its container. I've [made a Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qzQqmd#anon-login) with your HTML plus some sample text and it seems like what you're describing. Each child div scrolls independently of the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="col1" >
Mycontent 1
</div>
<div class="col2" >
Mycontent 2
</div>
</div>
.container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 35%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 30px;   
}

.col1 {
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
     position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.col2 {
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;   
   position: relative;
   float:right;
}
```

```
enter code here
```